# How to run HTTP connection from a front-end application

Tags: ssis, integration, quickbooks, httpconnection

I am integrating Quickbooks using SSIS to pull data into our SQL Server Database. The SSIS works fine but the problem is when I run the package from the front-end application. It cannot run it as the credentials to access the Quickbooks API are different than the credentials used to log in on the front end.

I have tried changing the packages and project settings to "DontSaveSensitive" but this causes blank files to be downloaded as it leaves out the credentials for the HTTP Connection.

I tried setting up the proxy tab as well but either get a bad request error, invalid URL error or unable to connect to server error.

Answer (score 1):

Issue was resolved.

The solution was to set the project protection level to "DontSaveSensitive" and then set up a variable for the server password.

In HTTP Connection properties, add an expression (ServerPassword) and set it equal to your new variable.